# Meta query "OR" comparison not working as expected with array

Tags: meta-query

I have this code to get cars that have color 1 or 0 (
stored in db in rw_color as 1 for white and 0 is black):

```
$args_search = array( 
        'post_type' => array( 'cars' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 99999,
        'meta_query' => array( 'relation' => 'OR' ),
);


$args_search['meta_query'][] =  array(
        'key' => 'rw_color',
        'value' => array( 1,0 ),
        'compare' => 'IN'
);
```

But the problem is that it never works for both 1 and 0 (no results are returned). It works only for 1 or when 0 is in array field like `'value' => array( 1 ),`  or `'value' => array( 0 ),` but `'value' => array( 1,0 ),` is not working.

Why is that?

How can I return results with value 1 **||** value 0 in `rw_color` meta field .

Comment: The code looks right and the generated SQL does too. Run `$q = new WP_Query($args_search); var_dump($q->request);` and post the output.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i am getting this: `string(555) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('cars') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'rw_color' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('1,0')) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 99999"`

Comment: You should get `CHAR) IN ('1','0')`, which I do when I test your code, not `CHAR) IN ('1,0')`. Is that a direct cop/paste? Are there filters effecting the query?

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes, it's a direct copy and paste. I didn't change anything.